# Chrome rendering hidden labels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've created a tab system using CSS which is working as intended, except that in Chrome one label gets randomly hidden.

I've created a small example to represent this issue: http://jsbin.com/xexupiciru/edit?html,css,output

This is an excerpt of the relevant code that represents a single tab:

```
<div>
  <input name="tagmanage-tabbed" id="tagmanage-tabbed2" type="radio">
  <section>
    <h1>
      <label for="tagmanage-tabbed2">{{ tabTitle }}</label>
    </h1>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

In Safari and Firefox this works as intended, but in Chrome, when a label is clicked, another label gets hidden by some reason and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your jsbin example is working perfectly in google chrome (mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is getting hidden in Google Chrome is that when you click on an element it makes it ever so slightly larger thus causing an overflow that it imperceptible to you. Google Chrome looks at the following rule and hides it:

```
.tagmanage-tabbed > div > section > h1 {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I removed this line, it wasn't being hidden anymore.